# Python Syntax Error: Invalid syntax. Can't figure out why?

Tags: python, dataset

WORK-AROUND FOUND: I downloaded Spyder and am able to complete my tasks using it. Still not sure why Anaconda Prompt is giving me the error.

I am working through a lab tutorial based around our AI assignment, and when I am entering the code provide for training datasets I am getting a syntax error that I can't resolve.
This is the comments provided to give context to the codes purpose;

Since LSTMs store long term memory state, we create a data structure with 60 timesteps and 1 output.
So for each element of training set, we have 60 previous training set elements.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, GRU, Bidirectional
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import math
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

def plot_predictions(test,predicted):
    plt.plot(test, color='red',label='Real IBM Stock Price')
    plt.plot(predicted, color='blue',label='Predicted IBM Stock Price')
    plt.title('IBM Stock Price Prediction')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('IBM Stock Price')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

def return_rmse(test,predicted):
    rmse = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test, predicted))
    print("The root mean squared error is {}.".format(rmse))

dataset = pd.read_csv('stock-20050101-to-20171231/IBM_2006-01-01_to_2018-01-01.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=['Date'])
dataset.head()

training_set = dataset[:'2016'].iloc[:,1:2].values
test_set = dataset['2017':].iloc[:,1:2].values

dataset["High"][:'2016'].plot(figsize=(16,4),legend=True)
dataset["High"]['2017':].plot(figsize=(16,4),legend=True)
plt.legend(['Training set (Before 2017)','Test set (2017 and beyond)'])
plt.title('IBM stock price')
plt.show()

sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(60,2769):
    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-60:i,0])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i,0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)`
```

I am geting an output of:

```
File "<stdin>", line 4
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If you're just pasting that into a shell, you need to hit enter after the second-to-last line. Otherwise it looks like it's part of the for loop to python

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this with Python 3.4. The `File "<stdin>", line 4` suggests that the code is not regularly executed.How is it called?

Comment: I created an environment (3.6 python) with all needed libraries (not part of labwork but couldn't get Keras working without). I use panda to read the csv dataset from file, and I can use matplotlib to show the plotted data. Straight after I scale to range of 1-0 and use this code resulting in this error.

Comment: Also I tried to split the command into two to avoid the for loop issue you mentioned. Using everything bar the last line first (runs fine) and then the last line (same error).

Comment: Can you post a more complete or reproduceable example? The error says `line 4` while the actual line in the code block is 6.

Comment: Edited to include complete code used up til that point. Hopefully the error will be reproduceable now.

Comment: could you replace this X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)`by this other and test please? X_train, y_train = np.array((i for i in X_train)), np.array((i for i in y_train))`

Comment: The exact same error message is displayed by replacing the last line of code to your purposed code